# I am trying to seperate my python files in diffrent folders when I try to import I get error No module named 'animal'

Tags: python

I have this file structure

```
- animal //this folder contains my pthon project
    - mamal (Folder)
         - dog.py //this is my dog python file
    - reptile (Folder)
         - snake.py //this is my snake python file
    - main.py // Is the python file that should access the mamal.py file
```

Here is my dog.py code

```
class Dog:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Dog"

    def draw_dog():
        print("₍ᐢ•ᴥ•ᐢ₎")
```

this is my snake.py code

```
class Snake:
    def __init__(self):

        self.name = "Snake"

    def draw_snake():
        print("===========*")
```

And here is my main.py code where I try to call the dog class

```
from mamal.dog import Dog

Dog.draw_dog()
```

but when I run main.py I get the following error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'animal'

Why is that and how can I fix this issues

Comment: Well, there is no module called animal... You haven't made it an installable _package_

Comment: try adding a blank file named `__init__.py` to the folder animal. also make sure that you really are at the directory you think you are.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I was about to ask why that question was even vaguely relevant

Comment: yes it does, have you "current workspace" be the folder containing `main.py` and `animals`, use `file->open folder`.

Comment: @AhmedAEK great for extensibility. So now you want to just have code working _only_ inside an IDE or actually fix the problem?

Comment: the more general term is "working directory" which different IDE's abstract away in different ways, a very valid question in the persuit of finding the problem. @roganjosh

Comment: I'm not convinced either of you actually know what you're saying here. _Nothing_ should be abstracted away by an IDE in terms of imports or package structure

Comment: lol the IDE will often set the working directory for you to the project/ workspace root, i.e. the abstraction. If that isnt set, thein lies the problem. There is also no reason to make it an "installable package", its just a module. @roganjosh

Comment: @roganjosh it depends on the steps you want to do to run the code, for example if you are deploying in production you'd have a bash script add that folder to `PYTHONPATH` before running the file, but if you were developing a library to push on pypi you'd create a `setup.py` and install it in editable mode, but if you are working on a script you'd just have it append its folder to `sys.path` at runtime, the only way that doesn't require extra steps is to make sure your IDE is on the correct folder.

Comment: @AhmedAEK well I wouldn't have a `setup.py` because that will blow up in Python 3.12... I'd have a `pyproject.toml`. And we're not talking about isolated scripts here. And appending to `sys.path` in a script at runtime is awful

Comment: @roganjosh pip still supports `pip install -e .` and will continue to do so for a very long time, so nothing is blowing up anytime soon.

Comment: @roganjosh OP most certianly is talking about isolated scripts. I have no doubt in my mind that he is *not* creating an installable package to be deplyoed via pip or easy install for drawings snakes and dogs. He's learning how modules work.

Comment: And neither of you are helping. I'm walking away from this.

Comment: @Bigbob556677 You are correct I am trying to understand how modules work And I would like it to work localy on my machine I do not want to deploy my code via pip

Comment: user class defination is wrong and in main file he need to do `Dog().draw_dog()` or make `draw_dog` a static method

Comment: @roganjosh you came here to gatekeep rather than offering a solution. Not very nice. lol

Comment: @Bigbob556677 I came here to make sense. What you're all talking about _makes none_. I didn't need your lecture on how to make packages or how imports work. Your suggestions are crap - if you rely on an IDE to set your working directory and it only works in that frame, then you have no chance of helping the OP

Comment: @roganjosh the suggestion was to set the working directory lol pretty cut and dry. *How* that is done varries based on OP's environment. Leading a beginner towards making an "installable package" is rather nonsensical when there quite certianly is a module called animal, one that he wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python3 used:

```
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jul 13 2023, 12:25:11)
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
```

operating system : macOS

this is working fine in mac, thing you need to modify is class where you define internal method without self or declaring it static method

this is what i done to replciate

file structure

```
├── animal
│   ├── mammal
│   │   ├── __pycache__ #ignore it 
│   │   │   └── dog.cpython-39.pyc # ignore it too
│   │   └── dog.py
│   └── reptile
│       └── snake.py
└── main.py
```

file content of snake.py dog.py and main.py

`dog.py` file

```
# ❯ cat animal/mammal/dog.py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Dog"
    def draw_dog(self): #<- added self
        print("www")
```

snake.py file

```
# ❯ cat animal/reptile/snake.py
class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Snake"
    def draw_snake(self): # <- added self
        print("===>")
```

main.py file

```
# ❯ cat main.py
from animal.mammal.dog import Dog

Dog().draw_dog() # <- update in usage
```

and now when we run `python3 main.py` we got output

```
# ❯ python3 main.py
www
```

running it from different location in system not in project itself, it works

```
# ❯ python3 /tmp/project/main.py
www
```

Comment: I am using a windos computer also I have made a mistake when I drew my file folder strucutre the main.py is inside the animal folder

Comment: @J.C if its in the animal folder, move it out of the animal folder and try. or just remove `animal` from the import line.

Comment: well then either you need to move it to same directory level as of animal or you need to modify usages (keeping it there)as `from mammal.dog import Dog`